# Пустые края у ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

Как убарть вот такие пустые края у imageView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте ширину в wrap_content поставить

Comment: после установки `wrap_content` изображение прилипло к левому краю, но справа все тот же разрыв

Comment: так же стоит отметить, что данная проблема только на планшете

Comment: ПОпробуйте вместо LinearLayout FrameLayout использовать и проставить нужную gravity там. А вообще - не хватает деталей о том, как оно должно выглядеть. Кажется, что проблема вообще не в картинке, а в том, как работает позиционирование виджетов в relativeLayout и как работают wrap_content и match_parent

Comment: а как вы хотите сделать? Чтобы изображение растягивалось? Обрезалось? Или что?

Comment: чтобы оно было по высоте контейнера и ширина была пропорциональная высоте. И чтобы блок находящийся справа от изображения был "прилеплен" справа от изображения

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не полный, вы в конечном то результате что хотите получить?
растянутое изображение или заполненное обрезанное?

1) В любом случае поиграйтесь с параметром *android:scaleType*

Лично я бы обрезал *android:scaleType="centerCrop"*

2) Раз проблема именно на планшетах, возможно стоит для них добавить свои ресурсы картинок через модификаторы, более вытянутые по ширине (широкофоматные) в связи со спецификой устройств, но centerCrop и в этом случае надо сделать чтобы каринка автоматически подгонялась в размер ImageView по меньшей стороне